# How to use constructor in expo camera?

Tags: react-native, camera, expo

I want to use constructor in my expo camera, but constructor does not work in function.
Maybe have ideas how to use constructor in camera?

Just need to constructor work on my camera, and maybe there are other ideas?

Put this code to the camera, example:

```html
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    reptile: 'alligator',
    color: '#008f68',
  };
}
```

Camera code:

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';

export default function App() {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={type}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            flexDirection: 'row',
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              flex: 0.1,
              alignSelf: 'flex-end',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
            onPress={() => {
              setType(
                type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                  ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                  : Camera.Constants.Type.back
              );
            }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 10, color: 'white' }}> Flip </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Camera>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write your own custom hook for functional component

useConstructorHook

```
function useConstructor(callBack = () => {}) {
  const [hasBeenCalled, setHasBeenCalled] = useState(false);
  if (hasBeenCalled) return;
  callBack();
  setHasBeenCalled(true);
}
```

include this in your app and use like this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';

function useConstructor(callBack = () => {}) {
  const [hasBeenCalled, setHasBeenCalled] = useState(false);
  if (hasBeenCalled) return;
  callBack();
  setHasBeenCalled(true);
}


export default function App() {
  useConstructor(() => {
    console.log(
      "This only happens ONCE and it happens BEFORE the initial render."
    );
  });
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={type}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            flexDirection: 'row',
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              flex: 0.1,
              alignSelf: 'flex-end',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
            onPress={() => {
              setType(
                type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                  ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                  : Camera.Constants.Type.back
              );
            }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 10, color: 'white' }}> Flip </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Camera>
    </View>
  );
}
```